# Help with asp.net mvc reflection and properties

Tags: asp.net, reflection, asp.net-mvc-2, properties

I need a way to dynamically populate this query... to avoid repeating the same query which I will have to do about 20 times

```
public decimal percentage_of_property(string property)
{
    var total = Routines().Where(r=>r.property==true).Count();
    return (decimal)100 * total / routines_total();
}
```

This obviously doesn't work... but I put it there so you can see what I'm trying to achieve...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Routine` is the type you can avoid reflection and use functional programming like so:-

```
public decimal percentage_of_property(Func<Routine, bool> propertyTest)
{
    var total = Routines().Where(r => propertyTest(r)).Count();
    return (decimal)100 * total / routines_total();
}
```

use it like:-

```
percentage_of_property(r => r.propertyName)
```